# Conversion from string "Price" to type 'Integer' is not valid

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

using vb asp.net

`error:` Problem with database (2). Conversion from string "Price" to type 'Integer' is not valid.

```
Dim testP As Decimal = reader3.GetDecimal("Price")
```

column price is decimal in database

Comment: What type of object is reader3?

Comment: You really should have `Option Strict On`, in which case errors like this will be picked up at compile time instead of run time. You should also pay attention to what Intellisense tells you about method parameters, including type and description.

Answer (score 3):

The `GetDecimal` method accepts a column ordinal only, not a column name.  The correct option would be to get the ordinal for that name:

```
Dim testP As Decimal = reader3.GetDecimal(reader3.GetOrdinal("Price"))
```

Alternatively, you could just get the `Object` reference from the `Item` property and cast it:

```
Dim testP As Decimal = CDec(reader3("Price"))
```

Answer (score 0):

this works

```
Dim testP As Decimal = Decimal.Parse(reader3("Price").ToString())
```

Comment: That's bad code. Converting a number to a `String` and back to a number should NEVER be done in such a situation.

Answer (score 0):

convert int to decimal

```
Convert.ToDecimal(reader3("Price").ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the index of the column you have retrieved. Say your Select looked like this

```
Select Name, Department, Item, Price From MyTable;
```

Then Price would be index 3. (Zero based)

```
Dim testP As Decimal = reader3.GetDecimal(3)
```